# Showing an ideal of $k[x,y]/\langle xy \rangle$ is prime

Tags: commutative-algebra, ideals

I am currently trying to show that the ideal $I = \langle x, y-1 \rangle$ is a prime ideal in $R = k[x,y]/\langle xy \rangle$ (for some field $k$).

My first thought was to rewrite the ideal as follows:

$\langle x, y-1 \rangle = \{ \alpha x + \beta(y-1) + \gamma (xy-x) : \alpha, \beta, \gamma \in R\}$

Since $xy=0$ in the ring, we rewrite this as:

$I = \{ (\alpha - \gamma) x + \beta y - \beta : \alpha, \beta, \gamma \in R\}$

But I quickly get stuck here.  I know I want to show that if $fg \in I$, then $f \in I$ or $g \in I$, but how would I do this in this case?  I can't see any nice way of doing it.

If this the correct way to go about this (and if so, could I have a nudge in the right direction), or have I gone the wrong way about doing it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm sure there is a simpler way: do you know the correspondence theorem between ideal of a ring and ideal of its quotients?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Joseph Curwen is right. The trick lies in the correspondence theorem.

Lemma.- Let $f: R \to S$ be a surjective ring homomorphism, $p$ a prime ideal in $R$ containing the kernel of f. Then $f(p)$ is a prime ideal in $S$.

Proof is easy.

Now apply this lemma to the factor homomorphism $k[x,y] \to k[x,y]/<xy>$. You only need to show that the ideal $<x,y-1>$ of $k[x,y]$ is prime. For this, recall that any polynomial in two variables can be written uniquely as:

$$f(x,y) = \sum a_{ij} x^i (y-1)^j$$

for some $a_{ij} \in k$.

EDIT:

This proof is incorrect. My apologies. The kernel is not contained in the prime ideal. Here is an idea.

We denote by $I$ the ideal generated by $x$ and $y-1$ in the quotient ring $k[x,y]/<xy>$. Denote by $\pi: k[x,y] \to k[x,y]/<xy>$ the quotient map. By the third isomorphism theorem for rings, we have:

$$\frac{k[x,y]/<xy>}{I} = \frac{k[x,y]/<xy>}{\pi^{-1}(I)/<xy>} \cong k[x,y]/\pi^{-1}(I)$$

So one only needs to show that $k[x,y]/\pi^{-1}(I)$ is an integral domain.

Comment: Ah yes, I am aware of this correspondence, but had seemingly forgotten about using it - thank to you and Joseph!

I wasn't aware about the way to uniquely write a polynomial of two variables though; I'll give a go at checking now!  I suppose that this can generalised to n-variables?

Comment: Hi! Sorry... notice my last edit. You need the prime ideal to contain the kernel, which doesn't seem to be true in your case. Sorry about the mixup.